# Fix LOAD DATA INFILE when an entry has a \n

Tags: php, mysql, regex, escaping, newline

I'm trying to load a csv file into my database using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."'
             IGNORE
             INTO TABLE ".$table."
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
             IGNORE 1 LINES
```

The file looks like this in a text editor:

```
header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6 header7    
column1 column2 column3  column4 column5 column7    
column1 column2 column3  colum\n4 column5 column7    <-- notice that sneaky \n in colum\n4
column1 column2 column3  column4 column5 column7
```

Each line is terminated using `\n` as it's in unix format. I'm calling the `LOAD DATA INFILE` using PHP.

Now when inserted into the database the function fails because the `\n` in `colum\n4` is treated as a new line separator.

what should I do? This is a legacy application that I'm working on, so I'm looking for the simplest modification to make it work.

### Update

- PS: I can't just delete the `\n` in `colum\n4` because it's part of
  the word (ex:  `Order \not shipped\ yet`). The file was sent to us
  like this.
- The file is sent to us by another company. We can't ask them to modify the way they generate it.

Comment: open file via editor remove this `\n` and load again?

Comment: The column should be enclosed, e.g. in double-quotes: `"colum\n4"`, then you can add an `[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY` clause to your `LOAD DATA` command.

Comment: @Robert the `\n` is actually part of the data. see my update.

Comment: @eggyal the file is sent to us by another company so we can't ask them to modify how they send it. Is there an alternative?

Comment: To be clear: does the file contain a literal backslash followed by the letter n, or does it contain a newline character (which you are representing in your question as `\n`)?  Whichever it is, how do you intend for MySQL to interpret that character/sequence?

Comment: @eggyal The data comes from a text box. One of the users entered `Order \not shipped\ yet`. The data was stored in the file as is. I want the text to be inserted as is into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify no `FIELDS` or `LINES` clause, the defaults are the same as if you had written this:
>
> ```sql
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
> ```
>
> (Backslash is the MySQL escape character within strings in SQL statements, so to specify a literal backslash, you must specify two backslashes for the value to be interpreted as a single backslash. The escape sequences `'\t'` and `'\n'` specify tab and newline characters, respectively.)
>
> In other words, the defaults cause [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) to act as follows when reading input:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - Interpret characters preceded by the escape character “`\`” as escape sequences. For example, “`\t`”, “`\n`”, and “`\\`” signify tab, newline, and backslash, respectively. See the discussion of `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` later for the full list of escape sequences.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` controls how to read or write special characters:
>
> - For input, if the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character is not empty, occurrences of that character are stripped and the following character is taken literally as part of a field value.
>
>   ```
>   [ deletia ]
>   ```
>
>   If the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character is empty, escape-sequence interpretation does not occur.

Therefore, to stop MySQL interpreting backslash `\` as an escape character within the imported files, specify a non-default escape character with `LOAD DATA INFILE`'s `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` clause.  If the file does not escape any input characters, you can simply specify the empty string:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."'
             IGNORE
             INTO TABLE ".$table."
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY ''
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
             IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: I'll try it, however how will it be able to distinguish between `\n` that is part of a word and `\n` that is a new line?

Comment: @Songo: Oh... do some columns contain newlines escaped as `\n`??  You will need to make that clear in your question.

Comment: @Songo: because "`\n`" != "`\n`" :) i.e: "a backslash character followed by a lowercase `n` (`0x5c 0x6e`)" != "a new line (`0x0a`)"